# Is it legal to use font I took from a school computer commercially if I turn it into outlines?

Tags: fonts, copyright

I have a bunch of fonts on my computer from my college that were from the school computers. I was hoping to use one of them for a commercial project (Akzidenz-Grotesk) and I'm a bit confused as to the copyright laws for re-use in this situation. If I use it and convert the text to outlines is it legal to do that? Also since I paid tuition to the school does that somehow grant me usage or no since I am now graduated form the institution.

I am in the US. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

You paid tuition which gave you right to use the computers at college, not to copy software or fonts from the computer and take it home.

The school licensed the fonts to be used on their computers, not to be used perpetually by all alumni in their personal computers.

Whether you convert the fonts to outlines or not is not relevant. You are not allowed to use them in your computer unless you pay for a licence of your own.

Comment: +1 The biggest problem that i have with copyright and licensing is actually the fact that it does not pass the "what would a normal person do", test. This is a good example situation the other is the i will put a image on a invitation from google.